# Angular 2 & 4 - Assign dynamically the a generated component

Tags: angular, components, inject

I am building a drag and drop, so when I drag and drop an element on the page I would like to :
1) Generate a component 
2) Assign it to the div that I just dropped on.

**The drag and drop is created already, and I figured out how to create the compoenent using ViewContainerRef**

**HTML**

```
<div #parent></div>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('parent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) parent: ViewContainerRef;

let childComponent = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TextComponent); 
let anotherChildComponent = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ullist)
this.parent.createComponent(childComponent);
this.parent.createComponent(anotherChildComponent);
```

What I am stuck on is that I can’t have the same   as when I drop the component the page the previouse one that is dropped get also updated as they share the same  #parent

I was trying to figure how can i assign the generated component to the one I clicked. Maybe generate a radom number and than insert the random number in ***ngComponentOutlet** and when I click I pick up the generated number  and assign my created component to it?

My app is built on Angular 4, so I tried **ngComponentOutlet**  and create a plunker that has 4 divs , When you click on a div I would like to assign component to it. Or insert it.
The way I have the 3 divs are through a **ngFor loop** that is generated f from an array.

What I want to get is that when I click on the DIV , I am able to to tell that specific ( specific I mean by I clicked on the div and each DIV has a ngComponentOutlet) ngComponentOutlet  what component it should inject.

Here is the plunker: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/JvXBLOVaeaYO5bmMQa6a?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, is there a typo in your plnkr? You have:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="loadComponent(item)">
    ...
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="items.componentSlider"></ng-container>
```

Should it be **item**.componentSlider, not **items**?

---

That said, you could attach an additional property like `isLoaded` on each item:

```
  items:Array<any> = [
    {
      name: 'slider'
      componentSlider: sliderComponent,
      isLoaded: false
    },
    {
      name: 'user'
      componentSlider: usersComponent,
      isLoaded: false
    },
    {
      name: 'slider'
      componentSlider: sliderComponent,
      isLoaded: false
    },
    {
      name: 'alert danger'
      componentSlider: AlertDangerComponent,
      isLoaded: false
    }
  ]
```

Then update your `loadComponent` method:

```
loadComponent(item){
    item.isLoaded = true;
}
```

And update your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="loadComponent(item)">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.isLoaded">
       <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="item.componentSlider"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/n3ocLxHKx32s2Fab52Zv?p=preview). The component is generated inside the `div` that was clicked. Does this accomplish what you need?

Comment: if i fetch the items from server i can't able to load the component

Comment: For ex:  {
      name: 'slider'
      componentSlider: 'sliderComponent'
     
    }

Comment: You can create a new array, and loop through the list of items you get from the server. For each item, create a new object that has the properties you need, and push it into the new array.

Comment: componentSlider: 'sliderComponent' but it not loading @Frank

Comment: The componentSlider value is string so it's not  rendering the html

Comment: You will have to map each component name to an actual component as you loop through the items you get from the server.

Comment: if the array of items count 25 from the server how can we map the component dynamically without using if (or) switch case

Comment: You can create an object that maps each component name to a component. Something like `let map = {  'slider' : SliderComponent, 'users': UsersComponent };`. Then in your item loop you can access it: `map[item.name]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145046/discussion-between-vignesh-and-frank-modica).

Comment: Please try it on your own first. Your initial `plnkr` had much more complicated code than this final part. I'm sure you can find a way to loop over an array of component names and select the correct component. You can edit my `plnkr`.

Comment: Thank's Frank i have completed the task. Without your support i can't able to do